# sklearn classification_report with input from pandas dataframe produces: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to run sklearn.metrics.classification_report with my data being in a Pandas dataframe.
The dataframe df_joined looks like this and has a 100 rows:

```
Timestamp    Label       Pred
2016-10-05   29.75  30.781430
2016-10-06   30.35  31.379146
2016-10-07   31.59  31.174824
2017-02-13   29.63  29.875497
2017-02-14   29.60  29.923161
2017-02-15   30.22  30.257284
2017-02-16   30.12  30.374257
2017-02-17   30.09  30.357196
2017-02-20   31.03  30.971070
2017-02-21   31.05  30.930189
```

I am now trying to print the classification_report by

```
print 'Classification Report:', '\n', sklearn.metrics.classification_report(df_joined[label],df_joined['Pred'] )
```

and I am getting the error:

> File
>   "\Python\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 106, in unique_labels
>       raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % ys)
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I have been trying to use `sklearn.metrics.classification_report(df_joined[label].values, df_joined['Pred'].values)` instead but it produces the same error.

Has someone a idea where this is coming from?

Comment: I guess it's because the unique values in `y_true` & `y_pred` do not match (either there are `NaN's` in `y_true` or some unseen value). As a result, it throws the error on encountering a value which isn't present and hence can't assign a valid label to it. Try to print out the unique values in both the arrays to check it it's indeed this case.

Comment: I have tried cutting the dataframe just to [0:10] values and printed them. ´df_joined[Label] = [ 29.75  30.35  31.59  30.71  30.2   29.66  29.71  30.32  30.77  31.36]´
´df_joined['Pred'] = [ 30.90649  31.56767  31.36999  30.38091  29.80005  30.301    30.93984
  31.30669  31.74146  32.21558]´   so they should be matching but I am getting the same error still.

Comment: also putting them as values in the function results in the same error ´print 'Classification Report:', '\n', sklearn.metrics.classification_report([ 29.75,  30.35,  31.59,  30.71,  30.2,   29.66,  29.71,  30.32,  30.77,  31.36],[ 30.90649,  31.56767,  31.36999,  30.38091,  29.80005,  30.301,    30.93984, 31.30669,  31.74146,  32.21558])´   is there any special formatting to be done?

Comment: Surely you should be using `'Label'` instead of `label`? I dont think its the problem here, though.

Comment: No, unfortunately the problem doesnt seem to be there. The code is embedded in a function, where I pass label as a variable which in this case is 'Label'.

Comment: what version of sklearn do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `classification_report` quantifies how well you have classified/predicted the *label* of a data point, not its actual value. A label can't be a float, all the examples in the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) and the [sklearn user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-report) uses integers for their labels.

The parameters also hints at this, as the alternative to passing a 1-d array is a specific array construct for labels only.

```
sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=None,target_names=None, sample_weight=None, digits=2)

y_true : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix

    Ground truth (correct) target values.

y_pred : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix

    Estimated targets as returned by a classifier.

...
```

If your data would have been integer-labels, the exact dataframe format you passed would have worked fine:

```
# Does not raise an error 
classification_report(df_joined['Label'].astype(int), df_joined['Pred'].astype(int))
```

You can read more about sklearn's different model evaluation tools in [Model evaluation: quantifying the quality of predictions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html), and pick one that is suitable to evaluate your classifier.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. As I am new to sklearn, I think I have been trying this Report in a way it is not meant to be used. When passing int-values it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you take them out as `list` types?

I.e.

`print 'Classification Report:', '\n', sklearn.metrics.classification_report(df_joined['Label'].tolist(),df_joined['Pred'].tolist() )`